# Radiator leak 92 subaru, repairs possible or replace?

Tags: radiator, leak, replace

Lower corner of radiator sprung a leak, was curious if self repairs were possible or recommended though my research would indicate it needs to be replaced. If I replace the radiator my self, since it was shortly driven with the radiator liked that and it smoked up twice or so, should I get it inspected for other damage after replacing the radiator? 
Pics of the leak
it's a 92 subaru legacy
https://gyazo.com/62522640e4b700afbdb62f0f8412412e
https://gyazo.com/70bc74e624143d494e3c9ee327f6eb95

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Radiators are pretty simple to replace. If you've never done it before, look at some youtube videos, and set aside about 4 hours for it (90 minutes, if you're handy with a spanner). Repairs on radiators are rarely successful - it's often a plastic sidewall that goes on Subarus. Sticking various concoctions in the radiator (or a raw egg) just causes extra - and more expensive - issues, because the heater matrix gets clogged up.

Will you have done further damage? Unlikely. Contrary to popular belief, a Subaru H4 engine can take a lot of abuse.

When refilling the radiator, it's recommended that you use the Subaru Coolant Conditioner. Get it from a local Subaru dealer for about $3.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend replacement, but a possible fix is JB Weld or similar.  Hard to say how long it will hold up.